# How to load all contexts of a Panels page?

Tags: panels, 7, chaos-tool-suite

The [Panels Ajax Tab module](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels_ajax_tab) is loading panes (minipanel pane) on panel pages via Ajax:

```
$pane = panels_mini_block_view($name);
echo $pane['content'];
```

This will get the contexts defined on the minipanel.
What I would like to have is the context that is defined on the host Panel page. I have a working solution for page manager pages, where context is 'static', so there is no argument but everything is fixed. The solution is ugly but works:

```
inject_panels_page_context($page_name);
$pane = panels_mini_block_view($name);
echo $pane['content'];

function inject_panels_page_context($subtask_id) {
  ctools_include('page', 'page_manager', 'plugins/tasks');
  $page = page_manager_page_load($subtask_id);
  $task = page_manager_get_task($page->task);
  $subtask = page_manager_get_task_subtask($task, $subtask_id);

  // Turn the contexts into a properly keyed array.
  $contexts = array();
  $args = array();
  foreach (func_get_args() as $count => $arg) {
    if (is_object($arg) && get_class($arg) == 'ctools_context') {
      $contexts[$arg->id] = $arg;
      $args[] = $arg->original_argument;
    }
    else if ($count) {
      $args[] = $arg;
    }
  }

  $count = 0;
  $names = page_manager_page_get_named_arguments($page->path);
  $bits = explode('/', $page->path);

  if ($page->arguments) {
    foreach ($page->arguments as $name => $argument) {
      // Optional arguments must be converted to contexts too, if they exist.
      if ($bits[$names[$name]][0] == '!') {
        ctools_include('context');
        $argument['keyword'] = $name;
        if (isset($args[$count])) {
          // Hack: use a special argument config variable to learn if we need
          // to use menu_tail style behavior:
          if (empty($argument['settings']['use_tail'])) {
            $value = $args[$count];
          }
          else {
            $value = implode('/', array_slice($args, $count));
          }

          $context = ctools_context_get_context_from_argument($argument, $value);
        }
        else {
          // make sure there is a placeholder context for missing optional contexts.
          $context = ctools_context_get_context_from_argument($argument, NULL, TRUE);
          // Force the title to blank for replacements
        }
        if ($context) {
          $contexts[$context->id] = $context;
        }
      }
      $count++;
    }
  }

  ctools_include('context-task-handler');
  ctools_include('context');

  $handlers = page_manager_load_sorted_handlers($task, $subtask ? $subtask['name'] : '', TRUE);
  $handler = $handlers['page_' . $subtask_id . '_panel_context'];
  $contexts_all = ctools_context_handler_get_handler_contexts($contexts, $handler);

  $current_page_ = page_manager_get_current_page();
  $current_page_['contexts'] = $contexts_all;
  page_manager_get_current_page($current_page_);
}
```

But this is still not collecting context that is using arguments, such as the current node (on the node_view panels page) or current user account (on user_view page). Those arguments are defined in `ctools/page_manager/plugins/tasks` - each of them separately.

What would be the preferred way of collecting all contexts, including, contexts with arguments and added contexts? Is there a cache that could be used?